# JSON.parse - invalid token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, parsing

In ASP .NET MVC I am calling a controller method that returns a `JsonResult`.

In my javascript, I'm trying to do this:

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
```

Where `data` is this:

```
{
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "ErrorMessage": "Test error message.",
    "From": null,
    "Notation": null,
    "To": null,
    "Valid": false
}
```

But I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
>       at Object.parse (native)

I have tried parsing the data on http://jsonlint.com/ but it parses OK there.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I am using AngularJS and I am calling the controller method that returns JSON like this.

```
$scope.move = function (to) {
    var x = $http({
        url: moveUrl,
        method: "POST",
        params: { gameId: $scope.game.id, fromPosition: $scope.game.board.selectedSquare, toPosition: to }
    });

    x.success(function (data) {
        var moveResult = JSON.parse(data);
    ...
    ...
    });
```

This similar call that is done before the above one actually works fine.

```
$scope.getGameModel = function () {
    var x = $http({
        url: gameModelUrl,
        method: "POST",
        params: { gameId: $scope.game.id, startingFen: $scope.startingFen }
    });

    x.success(function (data) {
        $scope.game = JSON.parse(data);
    });

    x.error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = data;
    });
```

Comment: Can you add in your AJAX call?

Comment: console.log(typeof data === 'object') is it true?

Comment: If your returning JsonResult (e.g. `return Json(myObject);`) then `data` is already JSON, so you should not be trying to parse it again.

Comment: I am trying to parse it into a javascript object.  I'll add my ajax call.

Comment: @TysonWolker: Yes it logs that it is indeed an object.

Comment: @PeteGO, Its already a javascript object. Trying to parse it again result in the error your seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use in javascipt as

```
var errorMessage = data.ErrorMessage;
```

No need to convert it in JSON.